# PHP Scandir with a conditioned foreach

Tags: php, html, if-statement, foreach, scandir

I would like to create a scandir command that would print an

to each folder

.
There's only one catch, I need to skip a specific folder if the name is XYZ.

Can you direct me to the trail I should take and where to start with this?

Thanks

Comment: I think the guy who answered me downvoted my answer because it took me too long to flag him as the right answer. Which I did at the end, but his damage was already done

Comment: I did not down-vote your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your question but from what I did understand I have made this:

```
<?php

$skip = "b";

echo "<ul>";
foreach(scandir(".") as $dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir) && $dir != $skip) {
        echo "<li>$dir</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

The code above will list every directory including `.` and `..` excluding the directory `b`.

You could also exclude `.` and `..` like so:

```
<?php

$skip = "b";

echo "<ul>";
foreach(scandir(".") as $dir) {
    if (is_dir($dir) && $dir != $skip && $dir != "." && $dir != "..") {
        echo "<li>$dir</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

---

Given the directory structure:

- .
- ..
- a
- b
- c
- d
- e

the first code snippet would display:

- .
- ..
- a
- c
- d
- e

and the second would print:

- a
- c
- d
- e

---

I hope this has answered your question.